# How can we apply Quantum Algorithms (Grover's to be specific) to edge coloring problem?

Tags: grovers-algorithm, speedup

I am a novice in the Quantum Computing field. Recently we were discussing NP-complete problems in Algorithms class and a question arose in my mind which I have stated above, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: For examples like this:
1. Implement a funcion that checks edges that are attached to a common vertices and increments a counter when their color is the same.
2. Use this function as an oracle in a Grover Search algorithm which looks for those combinations which have zero errors.

Comment: you find plenty of papers online for that, maybe you try to adapt the ideas of this one to your problem: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330069797_Quantum_Algorithms_for_Colouring_of_Graphs

Comment: I just came across this one: https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/blob/master/GraphColoring/GraphColoring.ipynb